# Should I say, The president of the college, together with the deans, 'is' or 'are' planning a conference for the laying down a series of regulations

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, verb-agreement, sequence-of-tenses

My question is what verb should I use in this sentence, The president of the college, together with the deans, (is)(are) planning a conference for the purpose of laying down a series of regulations. Could you please educate me on the rule of why it should use is or are?

Comment: There's this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/530545/singular-or-plural-verb-with-coupled-with although it doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: @StuartF Plus, the question sets out using a compound subject to begin with, and any discussion of a singular subject is buried in comments. Surely there's another dupe, though?

Comment: Either _The president is planning, together with the deans_ (singular), or _the president, together with the deans, are planning_ (plural).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular or plural verb form where subject includes a "parenthetical" element](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56210/singular-or-plural-verb-form-where-subject-includes-a-parenthetical-element)

Answer (score 4):

“Additional” phrases like *accompanied by*, *as well as*, *in addition to*, *along with*, and *together with* are not a part of the subject and do not affect the verb. The verb should agree with the subject:

> ***The president** of the college, together with the deans, **is** planning a conference for the purpose of laying down a series of regulations.*

Sometimes a reconfiguration can yield a more euphonious sentence:

> ***The deans**, together with the president of the college, **are** planning a conference for the purpose of laying down a series of regulations.*

Comment: Thank you very much @Tinfoil Hat. You have explained clearly which of the two phrases should the verb agree with. I was confused about the subject whether it was the president or the deans.

Answer (score 1):

The president of the colleges and deans are planning x.

**together with** is just not great writing and not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that if the subject is singular you use "is" and if the subject is plural you use "are". You probably know that but are unsure because of the additional clause.

So here's a second rule: Explanatory clauses like this are not part of the subject.

When in doubt, it is often helpful to strip out extra clauses and see what you have left. In this case, "The president is/are planning a conference." The subject is "president", so the verb should be singular, "is planning".

Note that you could reword the sentence to mean essentially the same thing but converting that clause into part of the subject. "The president of the college and the deans are planning ..." At that point the subject is "the president and the deans", which is clearly plural.